# Changing default db path in Phonegap

Tags: android, iphone, ios, cordova

I am using phonegap/cordova 2.1.0 framework for IOS app development. By default, phonegap looks for db in Library/Caches folder for IOS and in package_name/app_database/ for android.

My question is: can we change this and force the Phonegap to look for db in user defined location. For example, in iOS, I want the db to be created in /Documents folder, so can we let Phonegap search for db in that location and not /Library/Cache folder. If yes, how?

Comment: You may find this helpful. http://gauravstomar.blogspot.ca/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+GauravSTomarBootstrappingIntelligence+(Gaurav+S+Tomar+:+Bootstrapping+Intelligence)